# Can you skip properties of a structure in XML serialization VB.net

Tags: vb.net, class, serialization, xml-serialization

I'm trying to serialize a structure in vb.net. The structure uses types defined by other structures in the same class and types defined by structures in other classes. I can't serialize the other classes since they don't have a parameterless constructor, so I'm trying to skip them like so;

```
    Dim objStreamWriter As New StreamWriter(SavingAdd & " " & threadnum.ToString("000"))

    Dim xmlOver As New XmlAttributeOverrides()
    Dim xmlAttr As New XmlAttributes()
    xmlAttr.XmlIgnore = True

    xmlOver.Add(GetType(Namespace.Class1), "data1", xmlAttr)
    xmlOver.Add(GetType(Namespace.Class2), "data2", xmlAttr)
    xmlOver.Add(GetType(Namespace.Class3), "data3", xmlAttr)
    xmlOver.Add(GetType(Namespace.Class4), "data4", xmlAttr)

    Dim x As New XmlSerializer(maindata(threadnum).GetType, xmlOver)
    x.Serialize(objStreamWriter, maindata(threadnum))
    objStreamWriter.Close()
```

My understanding was each 'xmlover.add..' lines was allowing me to skip the serialisation of the named (eg. 'data1, data2 etc.) property of the structure.  However I still get the error that I can't serialize class1 because it doesn't have a parameterless constructor. **Where am I going wrong?**

Comment: Use the [`XmlIgnoreAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlignoreattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) on the field in the class you want to ignore.

Comment: Use a `Class` instead of a `Structure`